# My card Shuffler not working can any one tell what is the ambugity in that Shuffler

Tags: java, android

Try to shuffel 52 card of one deck with the random no.but this is returning same list as given. cardInDeck = 52;

```
public ArrayList<Card> cardShuffler() {
    int newI;
    Card temp,temp2,temp3;
    Random randIndex = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < cardsInDeck; i++) {
        newI = randIndex.nextInt(cardsInDeck);
        Log.i("Nulll", String.valueOf(newI));
        temp = cards.get(i);
        temp2= cards.get(newI);

        //temp3 = temp;
        //temp = temp2;
        //temp2 = temp3;
        cards.set(i, temp2);
        cards.set(newI, temp);

    }
    return cards;
}
```

Comment: How is `cardsInDeck` defined

Comment: also how is `cards` defined?

Comment: cardInDeck = 52 and cards is ArrayList of 52 cards

Comment: This have very low probability,, I have tried many time and result are same.

Comment: I've tried your code and after defining `cards` and `cardsInDeck` inside that method it works. So I think that the problem is outside of this code. Have you tried to view what's in the `cards` before returning it?

Comment: Have you checked if the program enters the loop?

Comment: One possibility (I'm guessing without the code calling this method) - You state that the method is returning the same list as given - are you sure you are assigning the return value of this method to something?

Comment: Yes this is entering in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `Collections.shuffle()`.

You can use it like this:

```
// assume `cards` is a `List`, 
Collections.shuffle(cards); 
// cards is now shuffled
```

For the curious, look over http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java on line 514.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is not in the code you've provided. Try this (added logging and cards initialization) and it works:

```
private void tryToSuffle()
{
    int newI;
    Integer temp,temp2,temp3;
    Random randIndex = new Random();


    //initializing data.
    Integer cardsInDeck = 52;
    ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i =0; i < cardsInDeck; i++) {
        cards.add(i);
    }
    //....

    //no change in the algorythm itself
    for (int i = 0; i < cardsInDeck; i++) {
        newI = randIndex.nextInt(cardsInDeck);

        temp = cards.get(i);
        temp2= cards.get(newI);

        cards.set(i, temp2);
        cards.set(newI, temp);

    }

    //printing the result.
    for (int i =0; i < cardsInDeck; i++) {
        System.out.println(cards.get(i));
    }
}
```

So without changing the main algorythm it works as planned.
So probably what your not doing is assigning the returned value to the proper variable. Why inside this method your using some instance field `cards`? Couldn't you pass them as argument?

**EDIT:**
Just to support what I've writen above I made this test, and it works (without changes in the shuffling algorythm):

```
public class ShufflerTest {

    private final Integer cardsInDeck = 52;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new ShufflerTest().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i =0; i < cardsInDeck; i++) {
            cards.add(i);
        }

        cards = tryToShuffle(cards);

        //printing the result.
        System.out.println(cards.toString());
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> tryToShuffle(final ArrayList<Integer> cards)
    {
        int newI;
        Integer temp,temp2;
        Random randIndex = new Random();

        ArrayList<Integer> shuffledCards = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        shuffledCards.addAll(cards);

        for (int i = 0; i < cardsInDeck; i++) {
            newI = randIndex.nextInt(cardsInDeck);

            temp = shuffledCards.get(i);
            temp2= shuffledCards.get(newI);

            shuffledCards.set(i, temp2);
            shuffledCards.set(newI, temp);

        }

        return shuffledCards;
    }
}
```

In the example I've added the `shuffledCards` array not to change the original `cards` array. This is good practice not to mess with the input param collection as you don't know if some other class uses it also. But if you decide not too use this additional `shuffledCards` variable it would work also.

My example output is (i've changed it to cards.toString() replacing the loop):
[46, 16, 23, 21, 28, 8, 37, 4, 47, 17, 9, 41, 51, 30, 20, 26, 10, 3, 2, 14, 29, 40, 25, 33, 34, 42, 15, 27, 32, 43, 39, 6, 22, 45, 31, 35, 48, 13, 5, 1, 12, 19, 49, 50, 44, 11, 7, 0, 18, 24, 38, 36]

Comment: Yes these are shuffeld with same algo but return same card.

Comment: What do you mean `return same card`? My output is shuffled.

Comment: Does the code above work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You need this fix:

```
public ArrayList<Card> cardShuffler() {
    int newI;
    Card temp,temp2,temp3;
    Random randIndex = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < cardsInDeck; i++) {
        newI = randIndex.nextInt(cardsInDeck - i) + i; // fixed here
        Log.i("Nulll", String.valueOf(newI));
        temp = cards.get(i);
        temp2= cards.get(newI);

        //temp3 = temp;
        //temp = temp2;
        //temp2 = temp3;
        cards.set(i, temp2);
        cards.set(newI, temp);

    }
    return cards;
}
```

Comment: i have tried before and this one is also produce 0 to 51. no need of it no. are generating well. I'hv check many time.

Comment: What does it change, how do you know it will fix things? For me it works great without your fix.

Comment: and if i do this will give Null Pointer Exception. if random no genrat 50 and 'i = 50' that will become 100 and this not a index.

Comment: no it can not cause if i = 50 then randIndex.nextInt(52 -50) will return 0 or 1

Comment: BTW, my correction is right in the mathematical aspect. You might still have issues with the deck of cards representation that makes your algo fail. To be convinced please read this p.281 http://www.mktechnicalclasses.com/Notes/Cracking%20the%20Coding%20Interview,%204%20Edition%20-%20150%20Programming%20Interview%20Questions%20and%20Solutions.pdf

Comment: But it doesn't solve OP problem. And you didn't explain why is that change necessary.